# how can I pass control value from parent window to popup window's code behind

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to receive value from parent's control to popup window's **code behind.**

for example

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoRate" GroupName="CouponType" value="0" runat="server" checked/>Rate
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoAmount" GroupName="CouponType" value="1" runat="server"/>dollar
```

and recive selected radiobutton's value from popup window's code behind.

My Solution is  make querystring  and  pass the value.

for example >

```
window.open(url + ?selectedRadioVal=" + $("#~~checkedradiovalue~~) .. blah balh)
```

and receive the value by  `Reqeust.Querystring.Get()`.

But I can't send very long string.  (maybe the url length is limited, right?)

Is there any good way to solve ?

Comment: I'm very sorry about my horrible English!

Comment: What will be the maximum length of the radio button value?

Comment: only for this example I use radio button,  I'm considering using textbox too

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you can handle this:

1. Hidden input control
2. Session

If you going to use this values in only one page then add that info to hidden control of the parent (using Javascript)

But it is easier to include this information in session and remove it when it is not required anymore.

HTH